# LNK1256: ALINK operation failed (80040405) : The key container name 'x' does not exist

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Every day I get this error:

> LNK1256: ALINK operation failed (80040405) : The key container name 'NameOfKeyContainer' does not exist

The only solution I have is to delete the key container with:

```
sn -d NameOfKeyContainer
```

and add it again with:

```
sn -i MyCertificate.pfx NameOrKeyContainer
```

Can someone tell me why I've to delete an create the key container every day?

(The certificate is a Verysign certificate)

Comment: When dose it happen? You state every day is it random or is it at a specific occasion, like start up? What OS do you use?

Comment: Not sure if it might help but here is a post with the same error atleast. http://objectmix.com/dotnet/91268-lnk1256-alink-operation-failed.html

Comment: Windows 7 Ultimate x64 and its happen every day, after switch on the computer. Sometimes (the most) morning, sometimes evening. I can't find a pattern.

Comment: A Verisign certificate must be added with signtool.exe and that's only done for the release build.  Hard to guess what you are doing.

Comment: My solution have some assemblies that must be installed in the GAC folder, so I've to sign them using the the flag /KEYCONTAINER in Linker/Advanced/Key Container.